# jQuery target parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html structure:

```
<ul>
<li id = "1"><a href = "">1</a></li>
<li id = "2"><a href = "" class = "active">2</a></li>
<li id = "3"><a href = "">3</a></li>
<li id = "1"><a href = "">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to apply the class of "active" to the li element with id 2. I tried the following:

```
if(jQuery('#navigation ul li a').hasClass('active')){
jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal In HTML5, it can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$('#navigation a.active').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

In your current code your `this` is invalid - there's no function doing the work so `this` doesn't get set to the element you think you're working on.

Rather than using `.hasClass`, use your selector to find the matching elements.  You can then use `.each()` to iterate over each matching element, correctly setting `this` each time:

```
jQuery('#navigation ul li a.active').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

This gives you code very similar to your original code.

Konstantin's answer is better, though - it avoids the need to manually iterate at all.  As a variation of that answer, if you're sure that every `<a>` element is directly contained inside the `<li`> that needs the class, you can use this:

```
jQuery('#navigation li > a.active').parent().addClass('active');
```

NB: your ID fields should be unique, and numeric IDs are only valid in HTML5.

Comment: Does `$('#navigation li a.active').parent().addClass('active');` enough here?

Comment: @JustinJohn the `>` is preferred to ensure that the `a` is a direct descendent of the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you use HTML4, your `id` should *not* be numeric only, start with letters instead like "id2" for example. Then just select the id

```
$('#id2').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$('#2').addClass('active');
```

The reason your code did not work was because the selector, '#navigation ul li a', likely returned many results, whereas your code assumes it returns just one.  If you are wanting to iterate through each element and test for 'active', try:

```
$('#navigation ul li a').each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".active").parent().addClass('active')
```

Comment: bad answer - the selector is not specific enough so it will propagate the `active` class all the way up the DOM tree if called repeatedly.